# add a blank file to the windows 'new' context menu

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

Whilst i have found posts that tell me how to add a new context item for a specific file type, i seem to be unable to see a way of adding one for a blank file (a la ubuntu). 
Is there a way of adding just a blank file (with no extension), which i can then rename myself with the appropriate extension?

Comment: I came across this question, just wondering if you found a solution?

Answer (score 18):

Create a `genericFile.reg` with the following content and add it to the registry. This will add a new context menu entry called "Generic file". A reboot may be required in order to let the entry appear. Or simply use [Shell New Handler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shellnewhandler/) and tick/untick the entry for the .dummy once.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.generic]
@="genericfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.generic\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
"IconPath"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\imageres.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.generic\ShellNew\Config]
"NoExtension"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\genericfile]
@="Generic file"
```

Comment: The icon doesn't match the empty file icon, for me anyway. This takes care of that: `"IconPath"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\imageres.dll,2"`.
It should be a child of `ShellNew`.

Comment: Tested and still works on Windows 10 1803

Answer (score 0):

The NullFile types create empty/0-byte "blank" files.  You can rename them to whatever you like, with whatever extension you like, and go from there.

Details about resolving the "new text document" being missing [here](https://superuser.com/questions/199030/windows-7-menu-new-text-document-is-missing-when-not-admin-user).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template for `.dummy` (or whatever unused extension you like) files, then add a flag to indicate they should be created with no extension.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Create a file called 'asdf.dummy'
2. Double-click on it, tell windows to always open it with notepad
3. In regedit, go to "`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dummy`"
4. Create the "`ShellNew`" key
5. Under "`ShellNew`", create an empty string value named "`NullFile`"
6. Under "`ShellNew`", create a key named "`Config`"
7. Under "`Config`", create an empty string value named "`NoExtension`"

Here's what I ended up with:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dummy]
@="dummy_auto_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dummy\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dummy\ShellNew\Config]
"NoExtension"=""
```