# ShellNew Icon for "." File Type

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, icons

I have successfully created a `ShellNew` command so that I can create a new blank file with no file extension, with the reg file being:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.]
@="emptyFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
@="Empty File"
"ItemName"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\ShellNew\Config]
"NoExtension"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emptyFile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emptyFile]
@="Empty File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emptyFile\DefaultIcon]
@="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\imageres.dll,2"
```

This works fantastic, creating the file just how I want it to, but the icon displayed in the `ShellNew` window is the icon for the System Partition [below]; how can I change this icon to match the DefaultIcon I am providing for the file type itself? 
 [image: Screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxNbv.png)

- I have tried making an "Icon" String Value like what I had to do for the Unity and Sublime Text menu items, but that did not work no matter where I put it

Comment: I can replicate. Trying to figure out if there's a way to fix it...

Comment: I suppose that you have not yet found a solution? I am thinking that there must be something in the registry stating that since it has no associated file type, it assumes it is a drive?

Comment: Looks like it, and if I had figured it out I would have posted an answer of course.

Comment: I can not seem to replicate this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, which works like magic, with the only change being I added an IconPath at the `.ext` level *(file type associations are amazing stuff!)*:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.]
@="emptyFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
@="Empty File"
"ItemName"=""
"IconPath"="C:\\windows\\system32\\imageres.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\ShellNew\Config]
"NoExtension"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emptyFile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emptyFile]
@="Empty File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emptyFile\DefaultIcon]
@="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\imageres.dll,2"
```

Comment: Another thing is, for the the ProgID's DefaultIcon you've set an expandable string, which really should have been of type REG_EXPAND_SZ instead of REG_SZ. Regardless, ShellNew doesn't seem to use the icon defined there.

Comment: Yep, that does it. Well done!

Comment: Wow, ~9 months old, and such a simple fix. Awesome job!

Answer (score 0):

Arent you supposed to use "imageres.dll,3" because its 3rd icon in imageres.dll?

You can try Default Programs Editor application, open program, click icons, find file type, click next, choose icon from imageres, and save as .REG file, then check whats inside that .reg.

Comment: You can't use Default Programs Editor for this because the file that it makes has no extension.

Comment: @orion310591: The index starts from 0. So it's technically the 2nd icon.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, this uses the same default icon as your `C` drive.

You can see this for yourself by creating the following key, if it doesn't already exist:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\C\DefaultIcon
```

And setting the (Default) to:

```
%SystemRoot%\\system32\\imageres.dll,2
```

[image]

[image]

I'm afraid I can't answer exactly why this behaviour occurs. There's actually another thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/221719/add-a-blank-file-to-the-windows-new-context-menu) that manages to change the icon with a different registry key though.

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to find the "Empty File" type in the FileTypesMan tool you might be able to change the Default Icon there.

FileTypesMan: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

Comment: I am under the impression that those kind of tools just do what the OP did manually, but I'll try it when I get time.

Comment: @BenN I guess you're correct - I assumed OP just wanted to 'fix' it but I guess they want to find a regedit solution.

Comment: Somewhere windows must be overriding the icon because FileTypesMan sees the correct icon, displays it there, and yet the ShellNew still displays the OS drive icon. This still is the case in Windows 10, even though I doubted that would have changed.