# How to restore my .txt ShellNew in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I don't know why, I cannot do New .txt in Windows Explorer any more, as you can see it has disappeared from context menu :

[image]

I looked at registry for .txt, I can't see anything to fix, but using shellnewhandler utility I can see description for .txt is empty, is it the cause ? where and how to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have "@%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe,-470" in HKLM\Software\Classes\.txt\ShellNew\ItemName ?

Comment: @PTwr I copy and paste from my registry : @%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe,-470 so yes.

Comment: Create a new user, does it appear then, update your question to indicate your findings.

Comment: @Ramhound finally got the solution from http://superuser.com/questions/199030/menu-new-%E2%86%92-text-document-is-missing-when-not-administrator-in-windows-7 I had to replace "txt_auto_file" by "txtfile"